# Customizing the json response for multiple testcases and validating it

Tags: java, junit5

While executing the junit and when it is going to sendRequest at highlighted line(marked as **) method getting below error.

> Unexpected character (S) at position 16.

Also i want to parameterize this createResponse method so that i can use that for different test cases, that's why i am passing different parameters to this method and json is created.

```
private HttpResponse<String> createResponse(int status, String message, String errorCode, String errorMessage,
        long number, long amount, String firstName, String lastName) {
    return new HttpResponse<String>() {
        @Override
        public int statusCode() {
            return status;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpRequest request() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<HttpResponse<String>> previousResponse() {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        @Override
        public HttpHeaders headers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String body() {
            
            return "{" +
            "\"responseCode\":" +statusMessage+","+
            "\"responseDescription\":null" +
            "}";
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<SSLSession> sslSession() {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        @Override
        public URI uri() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpClient.Version version() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}


@Test
public void testGoodValidateResp() {
    HttpResponse<String> response = createResponse(200, "SUCCESS", null, null, 997494, 500, "A", "AB");
    Mockito.doReturn(response).when(test).transmit(Mockito.anyString());
    try {
        response= test.execute(qcRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    assertEquals("Success", response.getStatus());
}


private Response sendRequest(String strUrl) {
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse;
        try {
            httpResponse = transmit(strUrl.trim());
            if (httpResponse.statusCode() == 200) {
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                String body = httpResponse.body();
                **JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(httpResponse.body());**
                String status = jsonObject.get("status").toString();
                if ("SUCCESS".equalsIgnoreCase(status)) {
                    return finalizeResponse(true);
                }
                return processHTTPFailure(httpResponse);
            } else {
                return processHTTPFailure(httpResponse);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return finalizeResponse(false);

        }
    }
```

Comment: this question needs more clarification. Paste your test class and the class you are testing separately. Is `sendRequest` the method you are trying to test? I don't see it being called. When you say `test.execute...`, is `test` a mock or spy object?